# Using ng2-file-upload with PHP

Tags: angular, ng-file-upload

I do not have an idea how to upload a file to **PHP** server using **ng2-file-upload** with Angular2. I don't know how to pass a **PHP** url to **FileUploader**.

I am trying to find something on internet about this, but nothing until now.

If it is possible, could someone give me an example?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** It works using ng2-uploader and following this [example](http://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader#backend-example-using-plain-p%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bhp) as @Chiragh Dewan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a lot of demo's available as well as a step-by-step guide.

[Valor ng2 File upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) (reference) and  [ng2 Uploader](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader)

Comment: Where did you found demo's using PHP on Valor ng2?

Comment: Valor ng2 File Upload is a reference. PHP example is with ng2 Uploader. [With simple PHP] (https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader#backend-example-using-plain-php)

Comment: So I will forget ng2-file-upload and try ng2-uploader... :( lets see if works

Comment: Just a question... Do you know if the url  "'http://localhost:10050/upload'" in the example, this "/upload" will gonna be my php file?

Comment: /upload is the folder where you'll be storing the file uploaded by the user.

Comment: Oh, Im confuse now... So where I have to call the php file?

Comment: Try adding your php file in www/ folder. So, there should two one file and one folder inside you www. www/test.php (the file you call) and www/upload (the folder where you'll be storing the files)

Comment: But I have to call this php file somewhere in the code, right? Where?

Comment: The url is the PHP file, now it worked! ng2-uploader rules :)